# get_list_display in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-tools

In my model admin, I would like to modify `get_list_display`.

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

      ordering = ['-date']

      def get_list_display(self, request):
           b[0] #<-just to crash it to see if it is getting called
```

However, it seems to not ever be getting called.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Haven't you modified `changelist_view` too? Also, better use `raise Exception` for hand brake

Comment: What version of Django are you using? `get_list_display` is only available since 1.4

Comment: yup.  I was using 1.3.  I have upgraded to 1.4 and it is being called now!

Comment: @dan-klasson you should put it as an answer so I can put it as answered :)

Comment: Alexis K: Yes you're right. I am a bit careful in general giving one liners as answers as technically it is against the rules. And moderators can be pretty anal about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_list_display` is only available since 1.4, maybe you are using an older version?